# Unity 3D to many game objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets, blender

I watched a YouTube video a year or two ago and I cant remember the topic that was being discussed but I know it was important. It was something dealing with making the memory or game objects in a scene smaller.

**So for example** lets say I have a blender asset that is a grass object. If I add movement to make it look likes its moving with the breeze then that will run for every grass object placed in scene. Before I start adding hundreds or thousands of grass objects around my map I was wondering if anyone knew what the topic is that I am trying to figure out.

So only one processes is being run for all multi grass objects, instead of them all running which will make game performance worse.

Comment: Based on the description I'd be guessing "instancing" or "batching"

Comment: @UnholySheep for instancing each object will be running the grass movement which is gonna be bad if there are thousands of grass objects, I am trying to get thousands of objects running on a single instance

Comment: @UnholySheep I read batching and it seems that only works for textures not moving objects or objects with scripts attached, So if they all have a movement script or something its kinda like thousands of moving objects in game which slows down game

Comment: Sounds like dots to an extent

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @BugFinder the solution to this is dots specifically ECS for reducing memory

Comment: `Converting your game to DOTS - Unity at GDC 2019`
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbnVELXf5RQ

Adding link here for the ease of others.